# ionic firebase phone auth . How to use recapcha?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase phone auth in ionic 4 with invisible Recaptcha. I have set ReCaptcha properties to window object. But still getting the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined

What has gone wrong?
Thank you in advance

window.service.ts

```
 get windowRef(){
    return window;
 }
```

page.ts

```
constructor(public win :WindowService){}

 ngOnInit() {

   this.windowRef = this.win.windowRef; 
   this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
    'size': 'invisible',      // error on this line

  });
 }

send(){
    const appVerifier = this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier;

    this.afauth.signInWithPhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXXXX", appVerifier).then(function (success) {

         // code sent  
}).catch(err =>{console.log(err})
}
```

.html

```
  <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
```

Attempt 2

```
this.recaptchaVerifier =new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      // same error
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're not importing `firebase.auth` yet.

Comment: I am not sure why but initializing firebase with firebase.initializeapp(config) in that page solved the problem. But I had already initialized at main page using angular fire

Comment: If those pages are loaded separately, then the load in the main page does not impact this second page in any way. Either way: good to hear you go it working!

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Can you please tell linkwithphonenumber() auto verifies otp or we have to implement sms retrive api?